# Set NIC Bonding Transmit Hash in EL9 with NetworkManager

Tags: linux, redhat, bonding, rocky-linux

I have just upgraded to Rocky Linux 9 and haven't been able to set the nic bond Transmit Hash Policy to 1. I'm using NetworlManager rather than the ifcfg files which is used by default in EL9.

I have tried the following steps:
#sysctl -w net.ipv4.fib_multipath_hash_policy=1
#cat /proc/net/bonding/nm-bond | grep Hash
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)

Also:
#echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/fib_multipath_hash_policy
#cat /proc/net/bonding/nm-bond | grep Hash
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)

Also:
#nano -w /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
Then added: net.ipv4.fib_multipath_hash_policy=1
And rebooted
Regardless It seems ot be stuck at Layer2 (0)

But I do get is working with:
#echo 1 > /sys/class/net/nm-bond/bonding/xmit_hash_policy

## cat /proc/net/bonding/nm-bond | grep Hash

Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
However, the setting isn't persistent through reboots.

What is the proper way to do this in EL9?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nmcli conn mod nm-bond +bond.options xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4
```

Comment: I tried that with the response:
]# nmcli conn mod nm-bond bond.options xmit_hash_policy=Layer2+3
Error: unknown connection 'nm-bond'.

so I i tried 
]# nmcli con modify Bond\ connection\ 1 bond.options xmit_hash_policy=Layer2+3
Error: failed to modify bond.options: failed to set bond option "xmit_hash_policy".

Comment: `xmit_hash_policy` is only applicable in `balance-xor`, `802.3ad` and `tlb` bonding modes. Have you set mode to one of these? Please have a look at `bonding.rst` in `kernel-doc` rpm for more info.

Comment: Yes, the mode was set to 4 / 802.3ad already. 
The answer that worked for me was posted on the Rocky Foums:
nmcli con modify Bond\ connection\ 1 +bond.options "xmit_hash_policy=1"
https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/bond-hash-policy-persistence-issue-in-rl-9-1/8459

Comment: Ok, I understand what happened. The command I proposed would remove the setting for bonding mode, hence the error. I've updated the answer.